# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I tried to download torch by using `pip install torch`

I faced this problem:

```
C:\Users\Ahmad Sadek>pip install torch
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

Comment: Please try `pip install -vvv torch` and see what it says.

Comment: using `-vvv` made it clear that none of the build versions match my current architecture (mine is `arm64`, which I found it by running `$ arch`), so it was not a python incompatibility (in case anyone is also spending a lot of time going through this rabbit hole)
thanks @Chris

Comment: Can you explain how you resolved that issue? I'm getting the same error but don't understand the outputs of pip install -vvv torch

Answer (score 6):

It isn't officially supported by 3.10 yet. Use the nightly builds:

```
pip3 install --pre torch -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu/torch_nightly.html
```

Comment: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Ahmad Sadek\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\caffe2\\python\\serialized_test\\data\\operator_test\\collect_and_distribute_fpn_rpn_proposals_op_test.test_collect_and_dist.zip'
HINT: This error might have occurred since this system does not have Windows Long Path support enabled. You can find information on how to enable this at https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/enable-long-paths

Comment: @AhmadSadekAlbasatneh you need to enable long paths, https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/enable-long-paths

Answer (score 2):

As per previous answers, python versions greater than 3.7 are not currently supported on the stable release.

Options are:

1. Keep Python > 3.7: Use the Nightly version - modify the installation configuration from [PyTorch website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) as per your needs (Win/Lin/Mac, CUDA version).  For example: Nightly, Windows, pip, cuda 11.8 is:

```css
pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu118
```

2. revert to an earlier version of Python, e.g. 3.7 and install Stable release of PyTorch.  E.g.:

```html
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
```

3. Use Anaconda which seems to resolve issues, eventually (see image)

[image: screenshot_anaconda_install_pytorch]

Answer (score 0):

This occurs if you are on a version of python greater than 3.7 on Windows.  PyTorch [specifies on their website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#windows-python) that versions later than 3.7 are not supported.  I had this error show up for me on my Windows machine when using 3.8.  After installing 3.7 and setting that as the default python the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem what worked for me is, I opened python in venv/scripts/python.exe  it was 3.11. something so I deleted the scripts folder and installed 3.10.6 and run webuser and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

install 3.10.6 version python, del venv file, and uninstalled earlier python version, and run webui-user.bat, it works

thankyou @impotent profile very it works

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35600591)